# How to make JTextArea blocks with height relative to content length, but with constant width?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to put JLabel and JTextArea into JPanel. There are few requirements for this JTextArea:
1. JTextArea must have constant width (approximately 680px).
2. Height must be relative to content. Content can be different.

```
    JPanel compilationErrorInfoPanel = new JPanel();
    compilationErrorInfoPanel.setBackground(this.getBackground().darker());
    compilationErrorInfoPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 10, 10, 10, this.getBackground()));

    JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea(errorInfo);

    jTextArea.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    jTextArea.setBackground(compilationErrorInfoPanel.getBackground());
    jTextArea.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 14));
    jTextArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 10, 10, 10, jTextArea.getBackground()));
    FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(jTextArea.getFont());
    int columnWidth = metrics.charWidth('m');
    jTextArea.setColumns(680/columnWidth);
    JLabel errorLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(Configuration.getProperties().getString("jresource.icon"))));
    compilationErrorInfoPanel.add(errorLabel);
    compilationErrorInfoPanel.add(jTextArea);

    compilationErrorInfoPanel.setPreferredSize(compilationErrorInfoPanel.getPreferredSize());
    compilationErrorInfoPanel.setMaximumSize(compilationErrorInfoPanel.getPreferredSize());
    compilationErrorInfoPanel.setMinimumSize(compilationErrorInfoPanel.getPreferredSize());
```

The problem i faced: 
if any content line longer than area width, JTextArea will creep out of JPanel.
I am using BoxLayout.
Is their any solution?

Comment: Have you tried to set a maximum size for the JTextArea? It should honor that value.

Comment: `JTextArea will creep out of JPanel. Is their any solution?` - This could be because of the layout manager used. The FlowLayout which will display all components in a single row. If there is no space for the component it will wrap to the next row, which may cause the component to be hidden. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with checking real lines amount.

```
      String[] lines = content.split("\n");
      int linesCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                linesCount++;
                linesCount += metrics.stringWidth(lines[i]) / (jTextArea.getColumns() * columnWidth);
            }
      jTextArea.setRows(linesCount);
```